# How flawed is this magic system?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems

In my Sci-fi/fantasy story, I have a magic system where there are specific "types" of magic (Incendiary, Electric, Hypnotic, etc.) and most humanoid species can naturally use these abilities without assistance of the bulky "Magic Mechs" used by humans. These "Magic Mechs" and other magic-centred technology makes use of the magical blue goo Magum. Magum alone is useless, though you can use it to heal wounds. You would have to either use incantations (which humans can't) or mix it with a certain substance to bring out certain abilities that match to the different types of magic (Mix with gunpowder for explosive properties, Arsenic for poison, charge it with electricity for shocking properties, etc). So basically, without a stockpile of different materials, the mechs are useless. Is there any way you can exploit anything or any other flaws with this system? Elemental weaknesses are nonexistent in this world. Alien magic is very versatile and can use whichever type of magic they know to use in any way they know how (Make a giant fireball at will, etc.) and there aren't specific attacks (like pokemon or harry potter)

Comment: The best magic systems usually have the most cheese. There's that thing with the "portable hole" that's a 3 meter cube you can fill with what you want, close, transport, and open anywhere you want. It basically means, if you can fly, you can dump 27 cubic meters of anything you want on your enemy. That's roughly 70 tons of rock, for example. Wham!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Flaws as Limitations

When balancing magic systems, several qualities make certain kinds of magic more or less versatile. A few common ones are:

**Ad-hoc vs Rote:**  Rote spells are specifically memorized or prepared spells, and ad-hoc are general descriptions of what sorts of things you can do.  For example, a rote system gives a wizard a spell called ice-bolt that does X amount of damage at Y range.  An ad-hoc system gives a wizard the power to create ice at will which he can use to create an ice bolt that does an amount of damage and range as he defines it following an algorithm of cost.  In general, Ad-Hoc magic systems are considered much more powerful because they make you more versatile and can often be exploited in contexts you don't expect someone to use magic for.

**Spontaneous Evocations vs Prepared Evocations vs Rituals:** Evocations are spells that can be called up in an instant.  In some systems, you can use spontaneous evocation which lets you use any spell that you have the power for whenever you want it.  Prepared Evocation is a bit more limited in that you need to do something in advance to ready a specific spell such as buying a scroll, filling spell slots, etc, but you can cast instantly.  Rituals need a lot of time to cast; so, you can not use them at all in situations like combat or to deal with other eminent threats so they are the least versatile.

**Internal Power vs Equivalent Exchange vs Reagents:** Internal Power systems limit your casters total amount of castable magic by their internal mana or spell slots where they can cast until they are exhausted.  Equivalent Exchange involves sacrificing something of value to cast magic.  This could be material wealth such as gold or diamond powder, or it could be more metaphysical like sacrificing your firstborn to extend your life. Reagents are like Equivalent Exchange, except you need specific materials for each spell. In general, Internal Power is more versatile, but it always comes with a hard cap of how much power you can summon in a single spell, whereas Equivalent Exchange and Reagent systems can be very exploitable in Ad-Hoc situations were things of vast value can be used to cast vastly potent spells.

**Power Pools vs Spell slots:** A power pool uses a total amount of power you have access to that can be dumped into whatever spells you need.  Spell slots are slightly less versatile because you have a set number of each spell you can cast.

**Classless vs Class Based:** Class-based magic systems allow users to only have access to groups of similar spells.  So a pyromancer can only cast fire spells, a necromancer can only cast death spells, etc. Classless systems are more versatile because they allow any caster to learn any combination of spells.

**Potentence:**  This quality is just a description of how powerful spells in a system are as s whole.  So, if you are trying to balance a Spontaneous Evocation caster against a Ritual caster and all other qualities of their magic systems are the same, then you can balance it by making Rituals more potent than the evocations.

**Endurance:** This quality is just a description of how many spells casters can use between recuperating.  So, if you are trying to balance a Power Pool caster against a Spell Slot caster and all other qualities of their magic systems are the same, then you can balance it by making the Spell slot caster able to cast more Total spells than the total power pool of the other caster would allow.

#### With these baselines established, let's look at your system:

Human magic sounds like it is based around a system that uses Rote, Prepared Evocation, Reagent, Spell Slot, & Classless magic.

Alien magic sounds like it is based around a system that uses have Ad-Hoc, Spontaneous Evocations, Internal Power, Power Pools, & Classless magic.

To balance human magic vs the alien magic you can use any combination of the following 4 factors.

1. Make humans magic more potent: By saying that an alien's biology limits how powerful their spells are, but human magic tech can be scaled up as needed, you could make an average alien foot-soldier more lethal than a non-magic human foot soldier, but then a 30ft Magic Mech or two can come in and wipe the floor with an entire alien platoon.
2. Make the Magum tanks on magic mechs able to slot a lot more spells than an alien could with its internal mana pool.  So the alien might be able to throw out 3-4 ad hoc spells then be exhausted, but the mech can shoot 50 fireball shells out of its fireball gun.
3. Curtail alien versatility in some fields and humans in others:  While humans need reagents to cast spells they have a truly classless system, perhaps the aliens need to study hard how to access each field of magic so that they are at least mostly class-bound.
4. Give humans non-mystical advantages:  Human magic might just be worse than alien magic, and that can be okay too.  Perhaps humans have access to technologies that can not be reproduced by magical means, or perhaps humans are more charismatics and cleaver making them good at manipulating aliens, or perhaps we have much shorter reproductive cycles so that humans can offset weaker individual abilities with sheer mass of numbers.

---

### Flaws as Oversights

The with a large number of constraints on the human magic system, it seems really limited, but there are two ways I can think of that humans could REALLY break the balance.

Since you say this setting includes aliens and mechs, I'm assuming humans have some manner of future tech at their disposal.  While humans may not be able to cast spells with the versatility of an alien, we have the technology to deliver spells so much better by not making it a function of our biology.  An alien has to see you to throw a lightning bolt at you.  Humans can fire a tactical missile from 300 miles away that comes in at supersonic speeds hitting you before the caster can even hear it to be able to respond.  (Magical additives are purely optional at this point)

Humans can also stockpile Magium to ridiculous levels.  Let's say a small magic mech can go toe to toe with a basic alien caster, and a heavy magic mech is comparable to an alien elite casters, why stop there? A starship is thousands of times the size of any mech and could thus perform thousands of times as much magic as any mech or caster.

I can imagine an army of aliens thinking they have the advantage on a battlefield, then a human star cruiser descends from orbit over the battlefield.  AI targeted support systems fueled by a hundred tons of Magum start reviving human soldiers by the hundreds, countering alien spells, and simply obliterating denser concentrations of alien forces.  Alien reservists who are not currently engaged in the battle try firing back but the magic shields on the cruiser are as potent as a small city of alien wizards making their attack useless.  On top of that the cruiser has dozens of 50cal machine guns that pick off any aliens who are too mired in combat to split their focus between the human soldiers in front of them, and the bullets raining down from above.

To address this I would suggest either make magium so rare that humans need to rely mostly on their technology using magic just on an as needed basis, or the aliens need to be able to apply enchantments to their own comparable technologies to also be able to magic mechs/cruisers/etc.

My Personal recommendation: I would go with making magium rare, and magic mechs significantly stronger than your average alien caster, while limiting alien technology.  You'll probably make a lot more interesting scenes with each side trying to figure out how to min-max against the other with such vastly different strength sets.  Then the Magic Mechs would just be your Hero units.  Too few to really determine the war, but so strong that you don't really notice the plot armor.

Answer (score 6):

## Badly flawed... just like all other interesting systems

Per [Sanderson's Laws of Magic](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Sanderson%27s_Laws_of_Magic), the limitations of a magic system are more interesting than its capabilities.  Some magic systems are designed with a very strict rock-paper-scissors hierarchy (water beats fire beats air beats water, for instance, or Alien Monster beats Squishy Humans beats Dumb Virus beats Alien Monster).  Those systems are *flawless*: there is one obvious right answer to how to solve a problem using magic, and all other answers are wrong.  These systems are not particularly interesting in worldbuilding or storytelling terms.

You've introduced a number of flaws (from the humans' perspective at least) in the system:

- Humans can't use magic 'natively', putting them at an immediate disadvantage against aliens
- Humans must protect the source of their Blue Goo
- Roving humans have access to a finite amount of magic (via Blue Goo ammo)
- Humans must divide their total magic resource amongst the different types of magic
- Each different type of magic requires additional resources and/or technology to 'activate', some of which are difficult and/or dangerous to carry in and of themselves

These are 'flaws' in the system in the sense that they can be exploited by an opponent to 'defeat' a human magician, but that doesn't make them flaws in the sense of making it a bad system.  *A system without flaws* is a bad system, because it is *uninteresting*.

Comment: "A system without flaws is a bad system, because it is uninteresting." I don't agree with this. It's entirely possible to devise a balanced and well-constrained system that _is_ interesting.

Comment: @Frostfyre a balanced and well-constrained system doesn’t allow a lot of room for improvisation and creativity.

Comment: @Roberto Why not? A system can be devised such that a given piece of magic M can be performed using components ABCD that behaves slightly differently if performed using components ABCE. Have the system define what each component does and how it impacts magic being performed and you have a system that allows for both improvisation and creativity.

Comment: I believe "flaw" in this context (and based on Sanderson's writing and lectures) is more akin to *limitations*, not oversights. Sanderson is a master of balanced, well-constrained magic systems. The limitations don't disrupt this balance, they reinforce it. These limitations are then what the characters are able to improvise and get creative with. Like if ABCD does one thing, but ABCX is invalid and explodes. The characters are surrounded and, having run out of D, face certain death, but then one of them finds some X and has an idea...

Comment: Separating "flaws" into "limitations" and "oversights" is a good way to talk about it.  Making a system more complicated doesn't automatically make it more interesting or more useful for worldbuilding: adding [twenty five](https://www.umop.com/images/rps25.jpg) different gestures to rock-paper-scissors doesn't make it any less the case that for a given problem (your opponent's move) you know exactly what the "right" answer is: the system has no limitations.   You _have_ to introduce limitations in order to be able to use the magic for anything interesting.

Comment: Bad flaws are ones that are overlooked by the author. Had they caught them, they might have been able to utilize them, or adjust the mechanics to prevent them. You want the reader to think "why didn't I think of that?" and not "why didn't they think of this?"

Comment: Flaws (as in limitations) should also not be confused with hidden mechanics. Having a character remember that ABCX explodes at just the right moment is not the same as having them accidentally get the recipe wrong, singe off the professors white caterpillar eyebrows and subsequently fail the class back in chapter 2.